# Low CPU usage polling architecture between 2 JVMs

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, low-latency, hft

**Server Environment**

- Linux/RedHat
- 6 cores
- Java 7/8

**About application :**

- We are working on developing a low latency (7-8 ms) high speed trading platform using Java
- There are 2 modules A & B each running on its own JVM
- B gets data from A

**Architecture:**

- we have made use of MemoryMaps & Unsafe. In this case, Module A writes into a memory mapped file & Module B reads from the file (both are holding address location to the file)
- We went ahead & used an endless while-loop to continue reading till the desired value is obtained from the memory mapped file

**Problem**

- CPU utilization shoots up to 100% & remains the same till its life cycle

***Question :***

Is there a more sophisticated way to keep polling for a value in the memory mapped file which involves minimum overheads, minimum delay & minimum CPU utilization? Note that every microsecond delay will deteriorate the performance

**Code Snippet**

Code snippet for the Module B (endless while-loop which polls & reads from the memory mapped file) is below

```
FileChannel fc_pointer = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
      MappedByteBuffer mem_file_pointer =fc_pointer.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, bufferSize);
      long address_file_pointer = ((DirectBuffer) mem_file_pointer).address();


    while(true)
    {
        int value_from_memory_mapped_file = unsafe.getInt(address_file_pointer);

        if (value_from_memory_mapped_file .. is different from the last read value)
        {
            //do some operation.... 
        //exit the routine;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
}//end of while
```

Comment: OK, how much worse is the latency if you use conventional inter-thread signaling, (eg. a semaphore), instead of CPU and memory-bandwidth wasting polling?

Comment: Also, if you desire high-performance, why do you have two JVM's?

Comment: Martin James, In theory, even for inter-thread signaling the spinlock is much-much better than locks in terms of both throughput ant latency. See for example well known https://code.google.com/p/disruptor/wiki/PerformanceResults Of course, cache missing can decrease the difference, but as I said "In theory..." :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Highly loaded CPU is the real cost of the lowest latency possible. In a practical architecture, which uses a lock-free signaling, you should run no more than just a couple of Consumer-Producer pairs of threads per CPU socket. One pair eats one or two (one core per thread if not pinned to single Intel CPU core with Hyper-threading enabled) cores almost completely (that's why in most cases you have to think about horizontal scalability when you build ultra-low latency server system for many clients). BTW, don't forget to use "taskset" to pin each process to a specific core before performance tests and disable power management.
2. There is a well known trick when you lock a Consumer after a long period of spinning with no result. But you have to spend some time to park and then unpark the thread. Here is a moment of sporadic latency increasing, of course, but CPU core is free when the thread is parked. See, for example: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf (8.4.4 Synchronization for Longer Periods)
   Also, a nice illustration for different waiting strategies for java can be found here:
   https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Getting-Started (Alternative Wait Strategies)
3. If you are talking about milliseconds (ms), not microseconds (µs), you can just try TCP socket communication over loopback. It adds about 10 µs to pass a small amount of data from Producer to Consumer and this is blocking technique. Named Pipes has better latency characteristics than sockets, but they are non blocking really and you have to build something like a spinloop again. Memory Mapped Files + intrinsic Unsafe.getXXX (which is a single x86 MOV) is still the best IPC technique in terms of both latency and throughput since it doesn't require system calls while reading and writing.
4. If you are still going to use lock-free and Memory Mapped Files and direct access using Unsafe, don't forget about appropriate memory barriers for both Producer and Consumer. For example, "unsafe.getIntVolatile" instead of first "unsafe.getInt" if you are not sure your code always runs on later x86.
5. If you see unexpected CPU utilization which should be no more 30-40% (2 utilized cores for 6 cores CPU) per pair of Producer-Consumer, you have to use standard tools to check what is running on other cores and the overall system performance. If you see intensive IO associated with your mapped file, then make sure it is mapped to tmpfs file system to prevent real disk IO. Check memory bus loading and L3 cache misses for the "fattest" processes because, as we know, CPU time = (CPU exec clock cycles + _memory_stall_cycles_) * clock cycle time

And finally, a quite similar and interesting open source project with a good example how to use memory mapped files: http://openhft.net/products/chronicle-queue/

Comment: If a spinlock-count is exceeded, there is no point in using sleep() calls.  The fallback should be to event/semaphore kernel sycnhro.

Comment: I didn't mean "sleep()" call exactly. It was a metaphor for parking/unparking of a thread (for example using OS mutex). Literally speaking, I meant this: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf (8.4.4 Synchronization for Longer Periods) An example of the trick http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/fa83ab460c54/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp  when we try to use CAS then spin and only then we park the thread. But thanks, I've updated my text a bit :)